# Quadratic program with nonlinear "perturbation" term

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I've the following "pseudo" Quadratic Program (QP). Suppose $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$

$$ x^{\text{opt}} = \arg\min_{x}  \,\,\,\,\dfrac{1}{2}x^{\intercal} M x + \dfrac{1}{2}x^\intercal T + \dfrac{1}{2}x^\intercal F(x) $$

where $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $(M + M^\intercal)$ is positive-definite, $T$ is any matrix with proper dimensions, and the mapping $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is nonlinear. I'm interested in using state-of-the-art QP solvers, which are extremely computationally efficient, but, of course, this problem is not "entirely" in QP form, given the presence of the mapping $F$.

**My question is:** is there any way I can treat this problem as a "perturbed" QP optimization, provided some condition in the norm of $F(x)$? I obviously don't mind if I lose some accuracy in the solution of the original problem... my application requires real-time performance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you only afford one QP solve? Or can you perform a number of solves? If the latter you can just use Newton’s method for this and it should be very efficient since the objective is close to quadratic. The starting point should be the solution if you do a linear expansion of $F$ in the objective.